# Are there Adobe AIR extensions to send crash reports from devices to an email?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, starling-framework

I'm developing a game on Starling (Adobe Flash/AS3). I use AIR to have both iOS and Android versions of my game. The game is rather simple, but there are scenarios that lead to app crash on devices. I would like to know if there are extensions for AIR to send me those crash reports on my email, in case problem happens somewhere on the users device.

If there are such extensions can you please tell me what they are ? If I'm asking the wrong question, please tell me what is the best practice to receive crash reports from an AIR applications ?

Comment: You can check out the Crashlytics ANE from FreshPlanet. It uses the Crashlytics service rather than email, though you might be able to get alerts. Sending directly from device to email is impossible, though.

Comment: Don't even need an ANE for this I don't think unless you want some custom logging.

Answer (score 0):

I find that its extremely easy to do this with as3 talking to php but that requires you to have a server to save that php script on. For instance if you have a website and you can save a simple php script on it and pass post data to it from the as3 side. I have an adobe air app that sends me an email when a user submits a new score so you could do the same just have it pass the crash report data you create. It is covered here http://www.dougtafoya.com/uncategorized/actionscript-3-and-php/

Of course this assumes you have access to a server to save the php file on but if you do pay close attention to the part in that post that shows how to send URLVariables when you upload to the php file. It doesnt show the email part there but you would just add a line like this to the php script i have shown there

`mail($to,$subject,"New crash report!",$crashData,"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");`

With `$to` being your email address, `$subject` a subject line, `$crashData` would be your data you receive through POST(look at that part in the link)

Hope this helps let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but the main thing is to GET the Crash Reports. I thought there is an extension or a device built-in solution for this.